How to center parbox like rest of the document?
Edit: I ended up using a quick fix for this : since it behaved correctly when I left the two columns, I simply set \onecolumn after the parbox and it worked.
I've started with this template : http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article
and eventually figured out I prefered complete lines over columns, so I removed them in the cls file. But now the parbox at the beginning has more margin on the left than the rest of the document. Any idea what could be causing this, or how to make a quick fix ?
This is the original cls code of the parbox:
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
    \twocolumn[{%
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \vskip-36pt%
        {\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
        \vskip20pt%
        {\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
        \vskip10pt%
        {\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont \@Authors\par}%
        \vskip18pt%
        \fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
            \parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
                \colorbox{color2!10}{%
                    \parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
                        \ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
                            \sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
                        \else%
                            \sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
                            \textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
                        \fi%
                    }%
                }%
                \vskip4pt%
                \begingroup%
                    \raggedright\sffamily\small%
                    \footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
                \endgroup%%
            }%
        }%
        \vskip25pt%
    }]%
} 

All I've done is remove the \twocolumn segment.

Can you try to make your question self-sustained? This will ensure that your question remains useful for future users even if your link stops working.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've added the original code I modified, is this what you meant by self-sustained ?

Self-sustained means that readers can reproduce the problem without visiting the link. Thanks  for adding a bit of code. It would be more convenient for anybody trying to help, if you could make a test file which we can copy&paste to reproduce your problem without having to modify it first.

\noindent\parbox ?
